# Excel: how do I insert 2 characters in a cell and then add the first 6 characters from an adjacent cell?

Tags: excel-formula

I want to have in cell A, two fixed character KO, then the first 6 characters from cell B. So if cell B says "Victoria", I want cell A to say "KOVICTOR"

Answer (score 1):

That's easy

> ="KO"&LEFT(B1,6)

Answer (score 1):

You could give the cell a custom number format of `"KO"@` and use `=LEFT(B1,6)` as @Raj suggested.

The cell will hold the value VICTOR but display KOVICTOR.

Maybe not the answer you're after, but a different way of doing it though.

Answer (score -1):

Use the formula

> ="KO"&LEFT(B1;5)

should work..